# How to use for-loop in Jython PythonInterpreter?

Tags: python, for-loop, jython

Is it possible and how to write down *for-loop* in `PythonInterpreter` using `exec()` method?

With `exec()` it looks fine and like interactive line by line input in the Python command line, but the following with `for` statement doesn't work:

```
PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter();
python.exec("import sys");
python.exec("for p in sys.path:");
python.exec("    print p");
```

Comment: "doesn't work' means what exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: @LutzHorn: I'd expect there to be a SyntaxError or perhaps an EOFError as the `for` statement is invalid without a loop body.

Comment: yes I do, the error is like: _... mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting INDENT"..._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in separate lines, how is Python supposed to parse those separately and validate that you have valid code?

Use one string:

```
python.exec("for p in sys.path:\n" +
            "    print p");
```

The `import sys` line can still be passed in separately because the namespace into which the module is imported is persisted in the `PythonInterpreter` instance.

In essence, each string passed to `exec()` must follow the [`stmt_list` grammar token](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-stmt_list); compound statements must be complete.

Comment: Thank you for your remark about `import`, cause it was my major concern which mislead and confused me that `exec()` behaves like interactive shell as it remembers what was in previous `exec()` calls.

Comment: Is it the only way to write _for_ statements in `exec()` ? For loop with more than one line I'd prefer to use something else then..

Comment: @rook: you need to pass in complete statements; a [`for_stmt` token](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-for_stmt) includes the full `suite` part; e.g. the body of the loop.

Comment: @rook: use a string builder first if you need to build the string dynamically?